# New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules using an unsupported plugin version (changes )

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, android-recyclerview

i am trying to add pagination with recyclerview android. In one project with the same code project is working very nice and  i am getting the position very well but in another project it just keeps on printing all the positions at one time. i don't know why. I thought it was error of old kotlin version so i updated my Kotlin version but then this error(New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules using an unsupported plugin version) is appearing when i importing the project.
here are some images
i have tried to update the kotlin version , but i thing this is not working. and showing error New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules using an unsupported plugin version even after updating the version to latest one.

```
              class Allplayer_adm_adp(
      val mylist: ArrayList<Model_class_one>,
                val fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,
                val pages: Int,
                val api: String
    ) :
                RecyclerView.Adapter<Allplayer_adm_adp.Viewholder>() {
                var currentpage = 2
                var loading = "no"
                inner class Viewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {  

                 lateinit var player_name: TextView

            fun mydata(list: Model_class_one?, position: Int) {                   
            player_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_name)
                        player_name.text = list.PlayerName
                        if (position == mylist.size - 1) {
                            if (pages >= currentpage) {

                if (loading == "no") {
                    loadmore.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    fragmentActivity.runOnUiThread {
                        Handler().postDelayed({
                            callnextapi()
                        }, 4000)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                loadmore.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        } else {
            loadmore.visibility = View.GONE
        }


        edit_menu.setOnClickListener {

    }
}
                private fun callnextapi() {
            //my api called and notifying changes
                    currentpage+=1
                }

                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1:                                 Int): Viewholder {
                    val layout =
        LayoutInflater.from(fragmentActivity as                 Context?).inflate(R.layout.allplayer_adp_admin, parent, false)
    return Viewholder(layout)
}

                override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mylist.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholder, position: Int) {
    val Values = mylist[position]
    holder.mydata(Values, position)
}
```

}

thanks for your kind help. any type of help will be appreciated

Comment: The question is not clear. You are asking about a gradle sync error and the code is about the RecyclerView, not the build.gradle.

Comment: all is what i m trying to say is that... my koltin version is not getting update, which is causing problems with my recyclerview.